# Why can jQuery calculate width on a server, but not when running locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I'm building a jQuery plugin that is working well on a server. However, if I try to use it locally, it fails because width and height are returning zero. The offending code is:

```
$("#off-screen").load(function() {
    var naturalWidth = this.width;   
    var naturalHeight = this.height;
});
```

...which is supposed to get the width & height of a dynamically loaded, off-viewport image with an ID of off-screen. I'm using this.width rather than width(); because I read somewhere it may help with cached images, but neither way works locally.

On a server:http://kthornbloom.com/smoothzoom/

Local (download from Github and you will see the images fail to scale correctly in **Chrome**): https://github.com/kthornbloom/Smoothzoom

**Why would the same exact code work on a server but not locally?**

Comment: Are you running this in chrome? You can't do AJAX requests in Chrome without a server.

Comment: Are you loading all necessary files or scripts?

Comment: @Mathletics Yes, you can. What you mean are CORS-calls, which are by default prohibited in all Browsers.

Comment: are you sure the load function is being called? Also, your naturalWidth and naturalHeight variables are local to your anonymous function, they wont be available outside that block.

Comment: @OP: Have you checked if your image really is loaded? I strongly believe you're violating same-origin policy. As a test, you can run chrome with the command line argument `--disable-web-security` or disable this setting in Firefox/IE and open your local file.

Comment: FYI- this does not use AJAX. When I said "dynamically loaded", I meant that jQuery is creating the image element on the page that I am measuring.

I can verify all resources are loaded

I think the code should only run after images are loaded unless I've messed something up there.

Comment: @OP If I download your webpage (with save page), it works for me locally the same way as on your server. (FF 19 ... I should really update)

Comment: Same here. They look exactly identical in the **latest** Firefox (26) <del>and Chrome (32.0.whatever)</del>. Actually, it's broken in Chrome, but not in FF.

Comment: Yes I can confirm that it works OK locally in Firefox. Just a Chrome issue. I wonder why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of just setting the `load` handler to an anonymous function that does nothing you should probably just put the code that depends on the image being loaded inside the handler.

This works on my machine:

```
$("#off-screen").load(function() {                       

    $('#lightwrap img').css({
        width: width,
        height: height,
        top: (offset.top - amountScrolled),
        left: offset.left
    });

    imageSizer();

    $('#lightbg').fadeIn();

    event.preventDefault(); 

});
```

Comment: Works perfectly and totally makes sense